# how can I Integrate Asp.Net Core WebApi With React.js?

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I Have a Project With Asp.net Core WebApi and React.js that BackEnd and FrontEnd of it are Running StandAlone Fine When I Publish On IIS Server(frontEnd Use Internet for call BackEnd Apis)

But I Wanna Use Asp.NetCore With ReactApp Template In VisualStadio To Integrate Those
And FrontEnd Call Apis On LocalHost with Same Application.
[VS template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdQau.png)

I Have Some Problem With Call WebApis with ClientApp(FrontEnd) Locally.
How Can I Solve That ClientApp Call WebApis Locally?

that is my JSCode that handel Connecting with WebApis :

```
import axios from "axios" 
import { BaseUrl } from "../utils/baseUrl"

const useRequest = ({ url, method, body }) => {
    const doReq = async () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
        const res =await axios(`${BaseUrl}/${url}`, {
            method: method,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"  ,
                "accept": "*/*",
                'Authorization':`Bearer ${token}`
            },                                   
           data : body
        })
        return res
    }
    return doReq
}
export default useRequest;
```

And Base Url :

```
export const BaseUrl = "http://localhost:44789"
```

My LunchSetting in BackEnd :

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:44789",
      "sslPort": 44367
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Project2": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need baseUrl in js file as above ,
url is enough, and url must be your endPoint route you declared in startup.cs + Http function name you want to access.

Comment: thanks man! I Saw Endpoints in Startup.cs and found solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample https://github.com/unpub777/PersonalPortal (I use this as template.)
I think you may to adjust something in your existing code following attached repo.